# PostgreSQL Sample Database Crow Foot Notation

Tags: sql, postgresql, erd

I have a question regarding the ERD below
[DVD Database ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC8Rj.png)

I am trying to understand whether I interpret crow foot notation correctly:

- a customer can have zero or many payments
- a customer can have zero or one rentals.

Payments part sounds good, but I did not understand rentals.

From the data, it looks like a customer can have more than one rental.

SELECT *
FROM rental
where customer_id = 459

this yields 38 rows.

Similarly from ERD I understand that staff can participate in zero or many rentals.
My questions, then why don't customer have zero or many relation with rental.

Here is a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables-rental.html) to DB documentation

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to erd the table should have constraing unique on rental; if it is yielding 38 rows it means constraint is not applied in the databased but is managed by the code which runs local on a computer and can have conflictions that is what constraints are for.

Comment: Oh so my interpretation was correct, right? Based on erd customer can have only one rental

Comment: Your interpretation of the ERD is correct. However, I suggest the error is in the ERD, and should be a 1:M relationship instead of a 1:1. A 1:M implementation is consistent with query. You should update the documentation (ERD).

Comment: Thank you so much